# How can reload list after update item by Visual Web Part in Sharepoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-2016

I created a visual webpart to update list data:
[image]

My code when click `submit` button:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists["Employee"];
                    SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
                    item["Title"] = txtName.Text;
                    item.Update();                    
                }
            }
        }
```

New Item had add to List, but List can't refesh.

I have to press F5, List will refesh.

How can reload list after update item by Visual Web Part in Sharepoint 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Response.Redirect to refresh the List View Page like this:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
          using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
          {
           
            SPList list = web.Lists["Employee"];
            SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
            item["Title"] = TextBox1.Text;
            item.Update();
          }
        }

      Response.Redirect("http://sp2016/sites/dev/Lists/Employee/AllItems.aspx");
      
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, i used: Response.Redirect(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);, to refresh target page.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different options to achieve this.
Either you can reload the page using Response.Redirect method.
Or after the update() instruction, recall the grid binding code that you must have used in page load method.